# Cast a dataframe to text following a hierarchical structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, hierarchical-data

I am working in `Jupyter Notebook` and I have a `dataframe` like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Parent': ['Stay home', "Stay home","Stay home", 'Go outside', "Go outside"], 'Child' : ['Severe weather', "raining", "Windy", 'Sunny', "Good weather"],
'Child1': ['', "some rain", "extreme windy", "very hot", ""]})


    Parent      Child           Child1
0   Stay home   Severe weather  
1   Stay home   raining         some rain
2   Stay home   Windy           exterme windy
3   Go outside  Sunny           very hot
4   Go outside  Good weather
```

I want to cast this `df` into a `txt`, save it and download on my PCs' `Downloads` file.

However, I want to save it into a hierarchical structure:

```
Stay home
     severe weather
     raining
       some rain
     Windy
       exterme windy
Go outside
     Sunny
       very hot
     Good weather
```

I uses the `pandas.DataFrame.to_string` method but is not adequate for these problem.

**Note:** This is a subset of my dataframe which actually has many rows

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not the most elegant way but I think it does the thing:

```
all=[]
for i in df.index:
    for j,text in enumerate(df.iloc[i]):
        if j==0:
            all.append(f'{text}\n')
        elif j==1:
            all.append(f'\t{text}\n')
        elif j==2:
            all.append(f'\t\t{text}\n')

with open('./trial.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines(all)
```

Edit: I realised you don't want repetitions, then this might be closer:

```
df2=df.groupby(['Parent']).agg({'Child': list,'Child1': list}).reset_index()



all=[]
for i in df2.index:
    all.append(df2.iloc[i]['Parent']+'\n')
    for text1,text2 in zip(df2.iloc[i]['Child'],df2.iloc[i]['Child1']):
        all.append(f'\t{text1}\n')
        all.append(f'\t\t{text2}\n')
```